# How to access the filters section of Photoeditor SDK?

Tags: android, photoeditorsdk

I am trying to build an android application along with using Photoeditor SDK (https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/  ;  Github - https://github.com/imgly/pesdk-android-demo). This repo has the complete code to use the SDK but I need only the filters sections from the SDK.

How to use that?

I tried implementing the dependencies and by making calls to the filters as given in its documentation,

```
ArrayList<<ColorFilter>> filter = new ArrayList<>();

filter.add(new NoneColorFilter());
filter.add(new ColorFilterAD1920());
filter.add(new ColorFilterAncient());
filter.add(new ColorFilterBleached());
filter.add(new ColorFilterBleachedBlue());
filter.add(new ColorFilterBlues());
filter.add(new ColorFilterBlueShadows());
filter.add(new ColorFilterBreeze());
filter.add(new ColorFilterBW());
filter.add(new ColorFilterCelsius());
filter.add(new ColorFilterClassic());
filter.add(new ColorFilterColorful());
filter.add(new ColorFilterCool());
filter.add(new ColorFilterCottonCandy());
filter.add(new ColorFilterCreamy());
filter.add(new ColorFilterEighties());
filter.add(new ColorFilterElder());
filter.add(new ColorFilterEvening());
filter.add(new ColorFilterFall());
filter.add(new ColorFilterFixie());
filter.add(new ColorFilterFood());
filter.add(new ColorFilterFridge());
filter.add(new ColorFilterFront());
filter.add(new ColorFilterGlam());
filter.add(new ColorFilterHighCarb());
filter.add(new ColorFilterHighContrast());
filter.add(new ColorFilterK1());
filter.add(new ColorFilterK2());
filter.add(new ColorFilterK6());
filter.add(new ColorFilterKDynamic());
filter.add(new ColorFilterKeen());
filter.add(new ColorFilterLenin());
filter.add(new ColorFilterLitho());
filter.add(new ColorFilterLomo());
filter.add(new ColorFilterLomo100());
filter.add(new ColorFilterLucid());
filter.add(new ColorFilterMellow());
filter.add(new ColorFilterNeat());
filter.add(new ColorFilterNoGreen());
filter.add(new ColorFilterOrchid());
filter.add(new ColorFilterPale());

config.setFilter(filter);
```

But I am unable to fetch it. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the FilterEditorTool as the only tool in your settings list.

```
SettingsList settingsList = new SettingsList();
settingsList.getSettingsModel(EditorLoadSettings::class.java)
            .setImageSourcePath(imagePath, true);

settingsList.getSettingsModel(EditorSaveSettings::class.java)
            .setSavePolicy(EditorSaveSettings.SavePolicy.KEEP_SOURCE_AND_CREATE_ALWAYS_OUTPUT)
            .setExportDir(filesDir.path + "/images");

ArrayList<ToolConfigInterface> tools = new ArrayList<>();
tools.add(FilterEditorTool(R.string.imgly_tool_name_filter, R.drawable.imgly_icon_tool_filters));

settingsList.getConfig().setTools(tools)

PhotoEditorBuilder(this).setSettingsList(settingsList).startActivityForResult(this, PHOTO_EDITOR_REQUEST_CODE)
```

Kotlin code:

```
val settingsList = SettingsList().apply {
    getSettingsModel(EditorLoadSettings::class.java)
            .setImageSourcePath(imagePath, true)

    getSettingsModel(EditorSaveSettings::class.java)
            .setSavePolicy(EditorSaveSettings.SavePolicy.KEEP_SOURCE_AND_CREATE_ALWAYS_OUTPUT)
            .setExportDir(filesDir.path + "/images")

    val tools = arrayListOf<ToolConfigInterface>(
            FilterEditorTool(R.string.imgly_tool_name_filter, R.drawable.imgly_icon_tool_filters),
    )

    config.setTools(tools)
}

PhotoEditorBuilder(this).setSettingsList(settingsList).startActivityForResult(this, PHOTO_EDITOR_REQUEST_CODE)
```

Comment: Hi, I am unable to replicate the above snippets. may I know how to use that?

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? You just need to add the FilterEditorTool to your tools in the settings list, this tool provides all the filters which are available.

Comment: I have all the filters but my question is how to use only the filters in the camera module that I already have in my project.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know if you can use the filters in the camera module, i think you have to pass the image from the camera to the editor and apply the filters there.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, will look into it!